# Bundling google-api-nodejs-client with browserify doesn't work

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-api, browserify, google-api-nodejs-client

I'm trying to build a client-side application with [google-api-nodejs-client](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/) using browserify. Looks like inside it is trying to read some mime-type info using fs module and fails to do it in browser.

```
    // Load additional types from node.js community
    mime.load(path.join(__dirname, 'types/node.types'));

    // Default type
    mime.default_type = mime.lookup('bin');
```

Did anybody use this API for client side development?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using the client-side Google JS library?

Comment: @Prisoner usually prefer to use something from npm if possible:) Yeah, I will use client-side library.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This question has been addressed and closed [here on GitHub](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/issues/193).

> fs is not available from the browser, unfortunately. This library is specifically designed and implemented for server-side development and is unsupported for client-side development.
>
> Check out https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/ which is designed for JavaScript client-application developers.